# How do I run mongo-express (without authentication)?

Tags: mongodb, npm

According to the official documentation for the web-based MongoDB admin interface **[mongo-express](https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express)**, one starts the tool using

```
cd YOUR_PATH/node_modules/mongo-express/ && node app.js
```

However, this does not seem to work. If I execute it on my system, I only get the "Usage" info console output. No error output. The same is true when using whatever combination of `username` / `password` / `database` parameters.

The `mongod` process works perfectly. Even the alternative tool *`mongomate`* (read-only) works fine on my system. I have created a simple `test` database, no authentication. All config settings on default.

Am I supposed to configure anything before using the application? I remember very clearly that I managed to get this to work very easily on another system some time ago, but now I just don't manage to get it started. Googling for "mongo-express" doesn't yield any helpful results either.

---

- mongod db version is v3.2.0.
- mongo-express version is 0.27.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after reinstallation with the current version it worked again.

Current Version of mongo-express version is now **0.28.8**.

---

Further investigation: After an experimental downgrade to the original version 0.27.6, it stopped working again, meaning that there was something wrong with that release. Upgrading to a newer version solved the issue.